# SELECT from database by date range not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get all data between a date range and export to CSV, right now the export its working, but something its wrong with the date range not getting the data from my database correctly, my code is:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT user_name AS 'Nome', cpf AS 'CPF do Titular', 
payment_method AS 'Banco', payment_type AS 'Tipo de Pagamento', other_bank AS 'Banco     Distinto', agdetails AS 'Agência', accdetails AS 'Número da Conta', amount AS
 'Valor da Transação', status AS 'Situação da Transferência' FROM $table WHERE status='paid' STR_TO_DATE('process_date','%Y/%m/%d') AND process_date BETWEEN '".$_POST['from']." 00:00:00' AND '".$_POST['to']." 00:00:00'";
```

What can be wrong here? i just checked the result for each variable and its sending the correct selected dates, but the data from database its not coming.

Thanks

**EDITED**

That how i'm running the SQL on phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT user_name AS  'Nome', cpf AS  'CPF do Titular', payment_method AS  'Banco',    payment_type AS  'Tipo de Pagamento', other_bank AS  'Banco Distinto', agdetails AS  'Agência', accdetails AS  'Número da Conta', amount AS  'Valor da Transação', 
STATUS AS  'Situação da Transferência'
FROM cashbackengine_transactions
WHERE STATUS =  'paid'
AND process_date
BETWEEN  '2013-09-12 00:00:00'
AND  '2013-11-27 00:00:00'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: have u tried to run this query in mysql ???

Comment: are u using phpmyadmin??? then u can run the same query there and check what answer u r getting with the values which u r getting corrrectly...

Comment: Well, just did it and for some reason its not working, but if i remove (AND process_date BETWEEN '".$_POST['from']." 00:00:00' AND '".$_POST['to']." 00:00:00') it return all the records, any hint about how to get date range?

Comment: buddy dont u know that inplace of $_POST['from'] and $_POST['to'] you shoul have to use the actual dates????

Comment: take random dates and just fire thew query and see the result. If you are getting correct answer then check the format of the date at coding side

Comment: yes, but i'm using them as variables, because i need to allow users to select different dates on the input, so i'm sending from a form the dates there.

Comment: i know that but dont u know how to run query in phpmyadmin????

Comment: Also i've tried as actual dates and dont worked, i dont know why, i'm using the correct date format yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Yes i know, i changed them to actual date numbers instead variables

Comment: ok then also not getting any???? are you getting any error for that??

Comment: no errors, just dont return any record

Comment: that means your date format is not correct or the range of date you are using is not having any values...

Comment: Check my edited question, i have values with today date, and its stored like: 2013-11-27 03:49:38

Comment: `2013-11-27 03:49:38` is not between `2013-09-12 00:00:00` and `2013-11-27 00:00:00`. Do you have rows in that range?

Comment: yeah buddy, you're right lol, now i have runned again with another range and its working, what a shame :(

Comment: Please post as reply so i can vote for the correct answer

Comment: @WilliamXavier- you should have to check properly befor putting up question here

Comment: @WilliamXavier added answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT 
user_name AS 'Nome', 
cpf AS 'CPF do Titular', 
payment_method AS 'Banco', 
payment_type AS 'Tipo de Pagamento', 
other_bank AS 'Banco     Distinto', 
agdetails AS 'Agência', 
accdetails AS 'Número da Conta', 
amount AS 'Valor da Transação', 
status AS 'Situação da Transferência' 
FROM $table 
WHERE 
   status='paid' AND 
   process_date BETWEEN str_to_date($from, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') and str_to_date($to, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
```

Assuming -

```
$table = "cashbackengine_transactions";
$from = mysql_real_escape($_POST["from"]); 
$to = mysql_real_escape($_POST["to"]);
```